# Silex add Routing file with all the routes to controllers

Tags: php, routes, silex

im using silex to create my API REST.
In a example, i found a way to create the routes

```
$api = $this->app["controllers_factory"];
$api->get('/notes', "notes.controller:getAll");
$api->get('/notes/{id}', "notes.controller:getOne");
$api->post('/notes', "notes.controller:save");
$api->put('/notes/{id}', "notes.controller:update");
$api->delete('/notes/{id}', "notes.controller:delete");
```

Im looking for a way to inlcude an array with all the routes and create and instance on my app bootstrap file. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. extend Silex\Application
2. add function which add routes based on parameters only
3. run foreach over an array of elements with needed params

**Example**

```
use Silex\Application as SilexApplication;

class Application extends SilexApplication
{
    public function addRoute($method, $route, $class, $callback)
    {
        $this->$method($route, array($class, $callback));
    }

    public function addRouteStatic($method, $route, $callback)
    {
        $this->$method($route, $callback);
    }

    public function addRoutes($routes)
    {
        foreach ($routes as $route) {
            $this->addRoute(
                $route['method'],
                $route['route'],
                $route['class'],
                $route['callback']
            );
        }
    }
}

$app = new Application();
$app->addRoute('get', '/notes', 'My\Namespace\Note', 'getAllNotes');
$app->addRouteStatic('get', '/notes', 'My\Namespace\Note::getAllNotesStatic');
```